# True or false statements with sets

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How can I do the following exercise?

$A$, $B$ and $C$ are arbitrary sets. Motivating appropriately the answers with proofs or counter-examples, establish whether the following statements are true or false:

- $A \cap (B \cup C) \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup C$;
- $A \cap (B \cup C) \supseteq (A \cap B) \cup C$;
- $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup C$.

Comment: Show your attempt please.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we know that $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$.

- For the first one, it claims $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup C$. This is true because we always have $A \cap C \subseteq C$.
- For the second one, it claims $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) ⊇ (A \cap B) \cup C$, which is false when $A \cap C \ne C$ (Take $A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{1,3\}$, $C = \{2,3\}$ as a counter-example)
- For the third one, we can use the same counter-example given in the second one to show that the statement is false.